# Weird visual force page issue on force.com site

Tags: force.com-sites, session

We have a force.com site which has a 50 step form. I login as portal user in say the first tab of the browser and let us say i am at page5. Now i create a new tab in chrome and go to the home page and i tried to click on a component which calls the first page of the same controller. At this point, the page breaks and i get a visual force error which says `Error occured while loading the page`. There is no debug statement and nothing on this error. So is there any way i can trace the line number on where this issue happens?
Here is the question.
On the home page of the site, i want to create a javascript which would check if the user is logged in already and force a site.logout to prevent this from happening. How can i do this on a javascript which will check if the user is logged in and if logged in, it will call logout jsp of salesforce or else will redirect to a new page with query string? Any sample code will help..

Comment: If you redirect to logout in one tab, your user will be logged out in all tabs, keep that in mind.